# Assigning references to Prefabs placed in each Scene

Tags: unity, scene, prefabs

I am currently working on a small 2D game which has a few different scenes, which are each a different level. I want to use my object prefabs from one scene in the others, but these do not include references to objects when I add the prefabs to my new scene.

Is it best to just manually add the references in the new scene to each object for every level, which is quite a long process, or is it better to change my script to use `Find()`?

What's a good practice when creating lots of levels with slight changes each time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Similar to an answer here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/203271/39518), an intermediate option you can use is to put the "Find" logic in `OnValidate`, so it runs once at edit time to save you the manual step of populating the references, without any runtime overhead in-build.

Something like this:

```cs
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour {

    // Save these references at edit time and allow editing in the inspector.
    [SerializeField] PlayerController _player;
    [SerializeField] Spawner _allySpawner;
    [SerializeField] Spawner _enemySpawner;

    // Run in-Editor only: when the prefab is placed in the scene,
    // on scene load, on enter/exit play mode, when any changes 
    // are made to this component instance in the Inspector,
    // or when reloading the script assembly after a code change.
    void OnValidate() {
        this.TryGetSceneReference(ref _player);
        this.TryGetSceneReference("Ally Spawner", ref _allySpawner);
        this.TryGetSceneReference("Enemy Spawner", ref _enemySpawner);
    }
}
```

Here I assume you probably want to wire up several of these dependencies, so I packaged the boilerplate into an extension method you can put in a separate file - so each call is just a one-liner:

```cs
public static class SceneDependencyHelper
{
    public static bool TryGetSceneReference<T>(this MonoBehaviour script, ref T reference) where T:Component {
        if (reference != null) return true;

        reference = Object.FindObjectOfType<T>();

        if (reference != null) return true;

        Debug.LogWarning($"{script.name} ({script.GetType().Name}) needs a reference to a {typeof(T).Name}, but none was found in the scene.");
        return false;
    }

    public static bool TryGetSceneReference<T>(this MonoBehaviour script, string name, ref T reference) where T : Component
    {
        if (reference != null) return true;

        var namedObject = GameObject.Find(name);
        if (namedObject != null) {
            if (namedObject.TryGetComponent(out reference)) return true;
        }

        Debug.LogWarning($"{script.name} ({script.GetType().Name}) needs a reference to a {typeof(T).Name} named {name}, but none was found in the scene.");
        return false;
    }
}
```

This handles doing no work if the reference has already been found, and logging useful warnings if the reference was not found.

Comment: Thank you so much! Very clear!